# What packages the man pages for GCC on Debian 10 Buster / Testing?

Tags: debian, gcc, documentation

I just installed `build-essential`, which installed `gcc-8` but the man pages seem to be unavailable.

```
$ man gcc
No manual entry for gcc
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Moreover, I can see that the man pages aren't provided by `gcc-8` (or `gcc-7`),

```
# dpkg -L gcc-8 | grep -i man
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gcc-ar-8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gcc-nm-8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gcc-ranlib-8.1.gz
```

I'm quite sure previously there was a `man gcc`. I'm using Debian 10.0 Buster (testing).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The manpages are provided in `contrib` packages, [`gcc-doc`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/gcc-doc) etc. (See the links at the top-right of the linked page for all the releases where the package is available.)

Debian 10’s default compiler is GCC 8. The GCC 8 documentation wasn’t packaged [in time for Debian 10’s release](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908589), but it is [available in backports](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/gcc-8-doc), along with [the corresponding `gcc-doc` package](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/gcc-doc). To install it, you need to enable backports with `contrib` and `non-free`, and install it from there explicitly:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports gcc-doc
```

---

Note though, even with `gcc-doc` you may want to install `manpages-posix-dev` for access to POSIX docs on ISO C standard library docs.

Answer (score 2):

The gcc-doc for Buster is not really available yet, but can be installed, with a bit of finagling, from buster-backports.  Hopefully this answer will become obsolete soon....  As root:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main non-free" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
apt-get download gcc-8-doc
dpkg -i gcc-8-doc_*.deb
```

It won't survive a `dist-upgrade` though because of the unmet dependency.